# I get this error Unexpected constant condition no-constant-condition and cant figure our how to pass this ,

Tags: javascript

I have this simple middleware but i keep getting this error

```
    export default function auth({ next }) {
    
        if (false) {
            return next({
                name: 'loginPage'
            })
        }
    
        return next()

}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `if (false) {`? Remove that whole block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a linter warning, telling you that the block:

```
if (false) {
```

will never be entered (or will always be entered), so there's no point to it.

Either remove the block entirely:

```
export default function auth({ next }) {
  return next();
}
```

If you're planning to add stuff to the block later, comment it out instead of putting in a runtime test:

```
export default function auth({ next }) {
  /*
  return next({
    name: 'loginPage'
  })
  */
  return next()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the keep the `if (false)` for a proper purpose, say debugging, try put the following comment above it to get it to bypass eslint.

`/* eslint-disable no-constant-condition */`

Make sure you remove this before your code goes to production.